# How do I implement autocomplete functionality for a big website?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, distributed-computing, trie

I am looking to implement a custom autocomplete functionality for a travel website with huge amounts of data. I am thinking of implementing it using a trie. But how do I handle it if the data cannot fit on a single machine. Also how can I get the top five items for a query.

Comment: Can you give us some numbers? How "huge" is this amount of data you're talking about?

Comment: Use a search engine like Apache Solr or Elasticsearch. They have all this functionality fine tuned to a level you most likely can't reach on your own. Also they can handle huge amounts of data with ease. I think it's unlikely that a travel website can't fit on a single machine, though if you have lots of traffic you may reach a level where a single node can't handle the load.  Elasticsearch can be very easily setup to run on many nodes and handle load balancing and duplicating the data over nodes.

Answer (score 2):

This is called **sharding** in MongoDB and **partitioning** in SQL Server. If the website actually uses “huge amounts of data”, sharding/partitioning is already implemented.

You may probably want to rethink what data you actually need to retrieve, how is it used and how do you store it. If you do auto-completion on product names, you probably don't need to retrieve the thumbnails of the products or the purchase history.

If there are actually terabytes of data, auto-completion might be useless. On the other hand, if autocompletion deals with a specific field like the name of the product or the name of the person, I can hardly imagine a case where the data won't fit on a single machine.

For instance, if you do autocompletion on names of persons and if we suppose that an average person's name is 20 characters in length, seven billions of persons on Earth leads to a maximum of 280 000 000 000 bytes, that is approximately 280 GB. On a single machine with 2 TB of space, you can store it seven times.

Comment: +1 for actually showing some math. People often spew the word "huge" when talking about data but rarely are they on point with their estimation.